# How to build linux kernel module using Yocto SDK?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to build a linux kernel module using Yocto SDK.
However, I am running into compilation error where it complains about

```
./include/uapi/asm-generic/int-ll64.h:12:10: fatal error: asm/bitsperlong.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/bitsperlong.h>
```

Here is my Makefile

```
ARCH ?= arm
CROSS_COMPILE ?= arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-
KERNELDIR ?= /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/src/kernel/
PWD := $(shell pwd)

.PHONY: build clean

build:
    $(MAKE) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c modules.order  Module.symvers

# Incorporate modules into a multi-part driver
my-objs := hello.o    


$(info Building with KERNELRELEASE = ${KERNELRELEASE})
EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-I$(PWD)/../include
obj-m := hello.o
```

Before I invoke make, I am setting up the source environment.

```
$source /opt/poky/2.7.3/environment-setup-cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi     
$make
```

Comment: The recipie might be missing a dependency of the kernel headers, try inspiration from other module recipes.

Comment: Any news  with this? I'm experiencing the same problem. @tannoy connect

Comment: I had to go to the SDK folder and had to run scripts and prepare command to fix those issues.

xx:/opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/lib/modules/4.19.0-xilinx-v2019.1/build$source /opt/poky/2.7.3/environment-setup-cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
uild$make scripts
$make prepare

Answer (score 8):

Had a similar problem with an out of tree kernel module, thanks to the comment of "@tannoy connect" it compiles now. Here are the essential steps:

1. Enable kernel-devsrc in SDK through your image recipe (see [Yocto Kernel Dev Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#working-with-out-of-tree-modules)

```
    TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "kernel-devsrc"
```

2. Install the SDK to your host, then run the kernel src makefile (thanks "@tannoy connect"):

```
    source path/to/sdk/environment-setup-aarch64-linux
    cd -P path/to/sdk/sysroots/aarch64-linux/usr/src/kernel
    # Note the -P argument: kernel is a symlink, in my case:
    # path/to/sdk/sysroots/aarch64-linux/lib/modules/5.4.0-xilinx-v2020.1/build
    make scripts
    make prepare
```

3. Compile your out of tree kernel module (note: my Makefile uses KERNEL_SRC and thus differs from the original question, because it is usually compiled through yocto module.bbclass):

```
    export KERNEL_SRC=path/to/sdk/sysroots/aarch64-linux/usr/src/kernel/
    make
```